# How to code the email composer cancel delegate method?

Tags: objective-c, rubymotion

I am building an iOS app using Rubymotion. I am using the build in email composer but I am having trouble creating the cancel delegate method.

*This is how it looks like in Objective C:*

```
-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error{

[controller dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

*This is how I started it in Ruby but it´s wrong:*

```
    def MFMailComposeViewController(didFinishWithResult:lambda{ |error|

    self.dismissModalViewControllerAnimated(true)

  })
```

Need help to convert from Objective C to Ruby.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a normal method. The lambda is unnecessary.

Also, you want an error pointer per RubyMotion docs: http://www.rubymotion.com/developer-center/guides/runtime/#_pointers

```
error_ptr = Pointer.new(:object)
def mailComposeController(controller, didFinishWithResult:result, error: error_ptr)
  self.dismissModalViewControllerAnimated(true)
end
```